# Which iterative method is best for finding the polynomial's root and why?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

So my lecturer has given us some work on iterative methods and I'm stuck on the second part of this question:

[image]

Using a calculator, I've figured out that **Method 2** is the best method to use. But that's by trial and error, so I can't really give a reason to my choice.

Is there a way to find a suitable iterative method?

Also, at the end, when it asks for an approximation correct to three decimal places. How can I know if it's correct to three decimal places without checking it with a calculator or computer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to compute Lipschitz constants resp. bounds for the first derivative over that interval.

Comment: There is a misprint in the second method, it should be $x_+=\sqrt{\frac16(x^3+4x+7)}$, mapping the interval $[1,2]$ to $[\sqrt2,2\sqrt{1-\frac1{24}}]$, which looks contracting, contrary to the other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments by @LutzL (including the error he spotted), we have

$$\tag 1 x_{i+1}=\sqrt{\frac16(x^3+4x+7)} = g(x)$$

We can use the following test (see these [*notes*](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/ftp/ENA_Materials/Overheads/sec_3-4.pdf) for theory) to determine if the iteration converges.

$$\displaystyle \max_{a \le x \le b} | g'(x) | < 1$$

For $(1)$, we have

$$\tag 2g'(x) = \frac{3 x^2+4}{2 \sqrt{6} \sqrt{x^3+4 x+7}}$$

The maximum of $(2)$ occurs at $x = 2$ and is

$$\displaystyle \max_{1 \le x \le 2} \left|\frac{3 x^2+4}{2 \sqrt{6} \sqrt{x^3+4 x+7}} \right| = 4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{69}} \approx 0.6810052246069989 \lt 1$$

So, this is a contraction and converges to the root. The iterations with $x0 = 1.5$ are

$1.5,1.65202,1.73766,1.78873,1.82017,1.83988,1.85238,1.86036,1.86548,1.86877,1.87089,1.87226,1.87314,1.87371,1.87408,1.87432,1.87447,1.87457,1.87464,1.87468,1.87471,1.87472,1.87473,1.87474,1.87475,1.87475$

Try this test on the two other methods.

Comment: Wow, this is new information. Thank you so very much.

Comment: You are very welcome and give a yell if you get stuck on the other two methods.